# Regular expression for unicode in java 7

Tags: java, regex, unicode

I have regular expression to validate number digits and -. I am now supporting mutibyte characters as well. So I have used unicode class to support but Its not matching. Can some one enlighten me on this

```
public class Test123 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String test="熏肉еконcarácterbañlácaractères" ;
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*$",Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS);

        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(test);
        if(matcher.matches())
        {
            System.out.println("matched");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("not matched");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: See the documentation for Pattern which has a full supply of Unicode character classes.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the posix class `\\p{Alpha}`, instead of literal classes with `[a-zA-Z]` to match unicode and accented characters.

**Example**

```
String test = "熏肉еконcarácterbañlácaractères";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\p{Alpha}+", Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS);
Matcher m = pattern.matcher(test);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

**Output**

```
熏肉еконcarácterbañlácaractères
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that despite that flag `a-z` doesn't represent "*all Unicode alphabetic characters*" but only "*characters between `a` and `z`*".

`UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS` flag adds Unicode support only to *predefined character classes* like `\w` which normally represents `a-zA-Z0-9_`.

So try with

```
Pattern.compile("^[\\w-]*$",Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[\\p{L}\\p{M}]+
```

You can use this to match `unicode` letters.

```
\p{L} matches any kind of letter from any language
\p{M} matches a character intended to be combined with another character (e.g. accents, umlauts, enclosing boxes, etc.)
```

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/fM9lY3/30